# Typescript props could be array of string or array of object with specific key:values

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a **prop** that can be an array of strings of image **URLs** or can be an array of objects with some `key-value` pairs where some `key-value` pairs are required and some are optional.

How can I set the type so I can verify that I'm getting either of them

```
interface Image {
  url: string;
  thumbnail?: string;
}

export class Props {
  public image: string[] | Image[] = [];
}
```

I tried this but it didn't work!

the props `image` could be:

`['url_1', 'url_2', '...']`

or

`[{ url: 'url_1' }, { url: 'url_2' }, { url: '...' }]`

Answer (score 0):

Try as below:

- Start name of any interface using 'I' before an actual name. It's used as best practices.

```
interface IImage {
    url: Object[],
    // This can get data in key-value pairs as below format:
      //  [{ 'url': 'https://www.google.com', 'url': 'https://www.twitter.com' }]
    thumbnail ?: string[]
}

interface IImage2 {
    url: string[],
    // This can get data as below format:
      // ['https://www.google.com', 'https://www.twitter.com' ..]
    thumbnail ?: string[]
}

export class Props {
    image: IImage;
    image2: IImage2;
}
```

Comment: Would that go fine for either `images = ['url_1', 'url_2', ...] and [{ url: '...' }, { url: '...' }, {...}]`

Comment: Brother, any of one format should be fixed either array of strings of image URL or it will be an array of object with key-value pair. If you yet want to use any of them then put url as any in an interface like below:


 `interface Image {
  url : any
}`

Comment: I understand but you have to go further with any of one format as it will create chaos and other problems in future. Though you want to go with both of them, you can use `url: any[]`. Yet I would suggest not to use it like that!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this  simply :

```
interface Image {
  url: string[],
  thumbnail?: []
}

export class Props {
  public image: Image;
}
```

Comment: What if the image is an array of strings?

Comment: you can do this like array of array [ ][ ].